# OpenCV createsamples and traincascade parameters (width and height)

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to create training samples (and subsequently train a classifier).  I'm confused about the `-h` and `-w` parameters used in createsamples and traincascade.  The examples I'm seeing typically use small values for these but my training images (negative and positive) are significantly larger (480x640) with the object I'm training for typically occupying 75-100% of the image.  It appears that these parameters are not asking about the size of the images (which it could simply pull from the images) but I suspect that it's also not asking for the size of the object in the image.  If I have to guess (and I would rather not), larger sizes might result in better detection accuracy, but would increase computational load during training.

Can someone please describe what these parameters actually mean?  Most examples I've seen use the defaults of 24x24 or upwards of 40x40, but never much higher as far as I can see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These small image values are the positives (the objects) that you want to train the classifier for. The object in your real frame might have an arbitrary size, because the cascade classifier works for various scales of the image.

[Here](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) is a good tutorial that helped me when I was training my own classifier. Your cropped images used for training might be bigger in size, but when you run `createsamples` you need to specify a size in which the positive textures are scaled. These new tiny samples are those that are used for the classifier. This also affects the speed of the cascade classifier, that's why they are tiny in size usually.

The background images can be bigger in size if I'm not mistaken, but I remember I was still cropping the background images I had in smaller pieces.

When your run your classifier with your real 640x480 data, you specify limits of the minimum size a positive can have (of course this value should be *at least* the size of the -w -h you specified before) and also the maximum expected size.

The haar detector will search for objects only in that range of windows in your test image that can be as big as you want.

Comment: The object that I'm trying to ultimately detect is pretty detailed.  Think of a sheet of paper with some paragraphs of text and some images.  I am struggling to understand how these tiny images would help when all the identifying detail is lost at that scale.  Am I using the wrong approach?  Should I instead be training for individual features on the "paper" (train separately for each paragraph or image?)

Comment: haartraining was initially used in face recognition, and its main approach is features of intensity. Something similar to what is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework). This scale works for faces then. It could also work for other objects, if they have enough variations in intensity. It is an approach based on differences in contrast and not patterns or edges, that's why small training sets help better.

Comment: I can't give you a specific answer if it is the correct approach for your problem, maybe someone else has more experience on this. But I know for sure that it can work for faces that are of bigger size even when the training set is tiny and that it also works for objects different than faces.